# Unable to delete from CTE - MSG 4405

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression, sql-delete

Why does this CTE give an error message?

```
;with del as (
    SELECT t1.*
    FROM t1 
          INNER JOIN t2
            ON t1.tid = t2.tid
)
DELETE del;
```

It gives the error message

> Msg 4405, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   View or function 't' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.

The exact same syntax works for an update, but not for a delete.

EDIT: the same syntax works if t2 is not a base table, but rather a cte base on constants.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dcc10/2

Comment: The error message is fairly self-explanatory: you can't delete from two tables. Your update probably worked because it only affected column(s) in one of the tables.

Comment: @ArronBertrand: But the CTE data only comes from 1 table

Comment: The data comes from a join which potentially means there is more than one row with the same primary key from t1 in the result.

Comment: `t1` is one table, `t2` is another table. A CTE is not a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question but here is a way to do this with a cte without getting the multiple base tables error:

```
;with del as (
    SELECT t1.*
    FROM t1
    WHERE
        t1.tid in (select t2.tid from t2)
)
DELETE del;
```

By using the in comparison it will be slower than a join but it allows you to have a single base table. Also, it's worth noting you can do this same type of delete without a cte entirely:

```
DELETE FROM t1
where t1.tid in (select t2.tid from t2);
```

and (best performance):

```
DELETE t1
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2
    ON T1.tid = t2.tid;
```